# block certain text from appearing on Shopify product pages in the description

Tags: shopify

I import my ads from eBay to Shopify (https://asiasell.com.au). In the product descriptions in the Shopify site I want to display only the text that is NOT related to eBay. I think if I do the opposite, hide eBay related text, then google might think I'm trying to hide keywords. It's a couple of paragraphs I want to NOT show. I'm going to guess that I add code to the timber.scss.liquid file. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Not sure, it's about coding and I saw very similar posts (that didn't help me) with responses.

Comment: It would definitely be about programming if you would [show the code that you have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But the question sounds like you are just trying to configure Shopify, which would be off-topic (that would be more of a general software question which you could put on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments say you question is very edgy in the sense that this isn't exactly about programming. However I would like to see what you've tried. For now I can just answer your question with Sudo.

You need to first find the `product.liquid` (*I don't know what theme you're using but this is just general*) and you need to do something like

```
 {% assign description_text = 'something that is in that text' %}

 {% if product.description contains {{ description_text }} %}
 hide  // this actually adds the class hide to this product 
 {% endif %}
```

Then in css somewhere you can do:

```
.hide {
       display: none;
}
```

If you ever need help with something like this then you can use the [Shopify forum](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/). To be franlky honest I don't see why those questions are accepted on Stack when Shopify have a whole forum for developers to discuss coding in liquid *specifcally* for Shopify.

Comment: Thanks. It is pop theme. So it is product-template.liquid. Your code failed for me on your second line (file wouldn't save). So I tried changing your code to <div class="product-single__desc rte" itemprop="description">
                   
{% if product.description contains "Are you having trouble" %}
 hide  // this actually adds the class hide to this product 
 {% endif %}    Seems I don't know how to enter code into Stack forum. I tried back ticks as per the instructions. Anyway, using this it put the word "hide" into the description. Wrong div though.

Comment: Well the code I wrote wasn't meant to work it was just an example of what you should be doing. Keep trying and like I said, you can get better help at the [Shopify forum](https://ecommerce.shopify.com) dedicated for problems with the problems like this. That is the best place to get help